# Running composer dump-autoload how can i

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-artisan, auto

please i want know
In detail step by step please

i will install plugin in script
Written on the plugin site

Run from the project root directory:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan rout:clear
```

how can i do it please

I have tried many tasks with no result

Comment: First in order to install a library via composer you have to do `composer install libraryName` 
Second it's `php artisan route:clear` not like the way you wrote it.
Also please edit the description with the output you've when you run those 2 commands.

Comment: sorry but i want some one Explain to me step by step
I don't understand laravel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You have the spelling mistake with your command. use the below command

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Welcome
Did you read the problem well?
I would like to explain in some detail, please how can i used command and  Where can I find command in project root directory

Comment: you should use Putty software or Winscp software to connect with your website in server and do the commands through that softwares or you can command through the terminal in cpanel

Answer (score -1):

you have open cmd then you have go to the project which you want to execute those command then you have to write those command.

> You have to be sure that you have xampp and composer.

Comment: Where and how to open cmd . in project ther are in directory composer.json and artisan